# App works fine in API level 19 but crashes when running in API level 21 Android

Tags: android, performance

my android app working in API 19 but when I tested on other API such as API 21 I got so many crashes in which I didn't find such in API 19. not that compile SDK version 23 this is so wired . dose anyone know how to fix this issue?

```html
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "co.lvlz.skiplino"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        multiDexEnabled true
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }

        lintOptions {
            abortOnError false
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please attach your stacktrace so we could assist....

Comment: try down compileSdkVersion ?

Comment: @mdtuyen to which number ? Actually i used 23 since i added library which run on api 23

Comment: Can you post the code from logcat when it gets crashed?

Comment: @Sharath ok l'll later . But do i specify ApI correctly ? Could you please have on code that i have post . i want my app work on ApI 19 as minimum and max 23

Comment: Ya as far as i know everything is fine in the Gradle.

Comment: Is this when running in the VS emulator? I'm experiencing a similar issue when running the VS emulator. I am able to run the same app on a phone with 21, just not in the emulator. And the emulator is fine with 19.